# Deep Conv Model number of parameters

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I was reading this claim:

> A CNN with two 5x5 convolution layers (the first with 32 channels, the
>   second with 64, each followed with 2x2 max pooling), a fully connected
>   layer with 512 units and ReLu activation, and a final softmax output
>   layer (1,663,370 total parameters)

I don't see how they calculate 1.6m parameters. The same network implementation gives me ~ 580k parameters which is more realistic given that this is a small network.

Comment: Where were you reading this ? Without the reference it's hard to give an explanation

Comment: Please also give the input image size. In addition, please consider the number of channels. May be you need to consider 3 input channels, and then your580k will become the claimed 1.6m?

Comment: @ArtemTrunov it's mnist 28x28 1 channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about MNIST images, 1 input channel, stride=1, padding=2

```
INPUT:    [28x28x1]   weights: 0
CONV5-32: [28x28x32]  weights: (1*5*5)*32 + 32  =       832 
POOL2:    [14x14x32]  weights: 0
CONV5-64: [14x14x64]  weights: (5*5*32)*64 + 64 =    51,264 
POOL2:    [7x7x64]    weights: 0
FC:       [1x1x512]   weights: 7*7*64*512 + 512 = 1,606,144
Softmax:  [1x1x10]    weights: 512*10 + 10      =     5,130 
-----------------------------------------------------------
                                                  1,663,370
```

Comment: I think you forgot the "final softmax layer", which is 512*10, but then it still does not add up to mentioned 1,663,370

Comment: @SaiBot, consider first layer, 5*5*32 = 800. Why is another 32 gets added?

Comment: @ArtemTrunov True forgot the softmax and more importantly had an error in the conv2 parameter calculation. Additional 32 are for the bias.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this cheating, but here is how 1663370 is obtained:

```
import torch.nn as nn

#First fully-connected (linear) layer input size as in the accepted answer:
linear_in = 7*7*64

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(1,32,5),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
    nn.Conv2d(32,64,5),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
    nn.Linear(linear_in, 512), 
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(512,10)
)
```

Now, the parameters:

```
sum([p.numel() for p in model.parameters()])
1663370
```

Layer by Layer:

```
for p in model.parameters():
    print(p.size())
    print(p.numel())

torch.Size([32, 1, 5, 5])
800
torch.Size([32])
32
torch.Size([64, 32, 5, 5])
51200
torch.Size([64])
64
torch.Size([512, 3136])
1605632
torch.Size([512])
512
torch.Size([10, 512])
5120
torch.Size([10])
10
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a hacky way to see this. The first answer is better imo and more intuitive as in order to obtain the 7x7x64 you really need to add 2-zero padding, otherwise the math doesn't work out.